# Spring batch local task launcher - Argument list too long

Tags: spring-batch

I am trying to launch spring batch worker using LocalTaskLauncher.

```java
HashMap<String, String> args = new HashMap<>(request.getDefinition().getProperties());
args.put(JMX_DEFAULT_DOMAIN_KEY, taskLaunchId);
args.put("endpoints.shutdown.enabled", "true");
args.put("endpoints.jmx.unique-names", "true");

try {
      Path workDir = createWorkingDirLocal(request.getDeploymentProperties(), taskLaunchId);
      int port = calcServerPort(request, true, args);

      ProcessBuilder builder =
          buildProcessBuilder(request, args, Optional.empty(), taskLaunchId).inheritIO();

      TaskInstance instance = new TaskInstance(builder, workDir, port);
      if (this.shouldInheritLogging(request)) {
        instance.start(builder);
        log.info("launching task {}\n    Logs will be inherited.", taskLaunchId);
      } else {
        instance.start(builder, getLocalDeployerProperties().isDeleteFilesOnExit());
        log.info("launching task {}\n   Logs will be in {}", taskLaunchId, workDir);
      }
      running.put(taskLaunchId, instance);

    }
```

With this I am getting the following error when running test cases:

```
Encountered an error executing step BatchJob:masterStep in job BatchJob [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] []
com.example.exceptions.ApplicationException: UNABLE_TO_INITIALIZE_BATCH
    at com.example.batch.tasklauncher.BatchLocalTaskLauncher.launch(BatcLocalTaskLauncher.java:108)
    at org.springframework.cloud.task.batch.partition.DeployerPartitionHandler.launchWorker(DeployerPartitionHandler.java:394)
    at org.springframework.cloud.task.batch.partition.DeployerPartitionHandler.launchWorkers(DeployerPartitionHandler.java:313)
    at org.springframework.cloud.task.batch.partition.DeployerPartitionHandler.handle(DeployerPartitionHandler.java:302)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy340.handle(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.PartitionStep.doExecute(PartitionStep.java:106)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:208)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:152)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:68)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:68)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.SplitState$1.call(SplitState.java:94)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.SplitState$1.call(SplitState.java:91)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.1/bin/java" (in directory "/tmp/85075662064908/BatchJobworker-65044ddf-f133-4894-a8a6-588ef994c89c"): error=7, Argument list too long
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at com.example.batch.tasklauncher.BatchLocalTaskLauncher$TaskInstance.start(BatchLocalTaskLauncher.java:253)
    at com.example.batch.tasklauncher.BatchLocalTaskLauncher.launch(BatchLocalTaskLauncher.java:102)
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=7, Argument list too long
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:340)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:271)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

Tech stack:

Spring boot: 2.7.2

Spring Batch: 2.7.2

Spring cloud deployer local: 2.7.2

I have tried the following options, which didn't work:

- increasing ARG_MAX
- increasing ulimit

I cannot reduce the size of env that is getting passed to worker from master. Is there some way to configure local task launcher to pass the env as JAR manifest or argfile?

EDIT: Options tried after posting question

I tried removing the following keys from 'args' map:

- "surefire.test.class.path"
- "java.class.path"

But somehow these keys are still getting passed again to worker in the command which is getting built.

Comment: Please check `getconf ARG_MAX` after increasing to ensure it has applied. Try Spring Boot 2.7.11 and Deployer 2.8.3

Comment: ARG_MAX I have already increased. Will try with the suggested boot and deployer versions as well.

Answer (score 0):

There probably isn't an easy way to make this work without making changes to your application.  You can try to debug this by working outside of Java and trying to execute the command directly in the unix shell and see if that helps.  Otherwise, shift arguments to environment variables or look up configuration information in some other way in your app.

Comment: For some reason, this error in only occurring when I run maven tests in ubuntu. On windows, I don't get this error at all.

Comment: the issue is that the env itself is getting too large. local task launcher in application is attaching the entire class path twice: once under java class path and once under surefire test class path.
Editing the question to add more options that I tried after posting the question.